# Excel month formula

Tags: excel-formula

I want to show specific text for whether something is due for any given month in a financial year or overdue if that month has passed. The formula I am using is as below and works fine until I get to January.

I am using the numerals 7-12 in this formula to represent respective month but am unsure how to ensure the number 1 relates to the next year. For that matter I guess my equation below for overdue for December won't work either.

```
=IF(MONTH(TODAY())=12,"DUE",IF(MONTH(TODAY())<=12,"",IF(MONTH(TODAY())>=12,"Overdue")))
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: At best you could include also the year for comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the month number, let A1 equal the first of the month in which it's due.  (Note the first of the month is what you'll get if you just type in the month and year, eg `August 2014`)

```
=IF(TODAY()<A1,"",IF(TODAY()>EOMONTH(A1,0),"Overdue","Due"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that you can use. This includes a `=YEAR(` function and an `=AND` function to extend on what you already have.

The formula you can use is here.

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH(A2),YEAR(TODAY())=YEAR(A2)),"Due",IF(AND(MONTH(TODAY())>MONTH(A2),YEAR(TODAY())>=YEAR(A2)),"Overdue",""))
```

you can add the year into the comparison which will eliminate your problems with January.

Just wrap the month check and year check in an `=AND(` function when both conditions are `TRUE` you can enter your result.

[image: Working Example]